# Email text display as attachment

Tags: exchange-server

I have created a journal rules in exchange server2010 to get all incoming and outgoing messages. When I try to view the email in outlook,the body of that mail only contain a message id

for e.g. 
Message-Id: <7D927CB4950DBB4C8964E46C285F086E025E255D@ex.xxx.com>

and mail contents display in an attachment. If I view that attachment then I can see the message.
I need to fetch all details of that mail including body. Is there any settings for that which I am missing.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which language do yout intend to use to retrieve the mails? Please give more information about your environment.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the Journal Envelope.  This is how Exchange 2010 handles journaling, by wrapping the original message and typically including the recipients of the message in the body.

You question isn't very clear.  Is there a reason you can't just process the embedded message and read the body?  It is a standard message, just as an attachment.  As Henning commented, there isn't enough information to help you further.